# Invalid Use of Null in Dropdown VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following code for my dropdown menu

```
Private Sub cmb_Name_AfterUpdate()
Dim strFilter As String
Me.cmb_WorkCity.Requery
strFilter = "[Employee Name]='" & Replace(Me.cmb_Name.Column(0), "'", "''") & _
            "' And [Movement Type]='" & Me.cmb_Name.Column(1) & "'"
Debug.Print strFilter '
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , strFilter
End Sub
```

It works for every single cmb_WorkCity except one city where all Employee Names that I select result in an Invalid Use of Null, I'm pulling my hair right now because anything I change results in the same thing. The code worked previously, it just stopped working today randomly.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Can you please provide an example value that works, and one that does not work ?

Comment: So for instance, if WorkCity was Columbus, and the person's name was Smith,John it works, if WorkCity is Dublin (and this only happens in this case) all the names under Dublin result in this error. The replace function I put in place to help with cases like O'Mailey in the last name. Access did not like the ' in the name so had to replace it.

Comment: I used mdialogo's suggestion below and this is what debug.print results in the para noted below. The first two being part of "Columbus" as a WorkCity and the second two being "Dublin", I look at the overall data, nothing really makes the two different in terms data content and structure.

Comment: [Employee Name]='Jones,Melika' And [Movement Type]='Term'
[Employee Name]='MacGuinness,Neil' And [Movement Type]='Term'
[Employee Name]='' And [Movement Type]=''
[Employee Name]='' And [Movement Type]=''

Comment: I found the issue, it was pertaining to a datapoint that was not filled out in the table, thank you all again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` doesn't like `null` so you must enclosed `Me.cmb_Name` with `Nz()` function like this:

```
Private Sub cmb_Name_AfterUpdate()
Dim strFilter As String
Me.cmb_WorkCity.Requery
strFilter = "[Employee Name]='" & Replace(Nz(Me.cmb_Name.Column(0)), "'", "''") & _
            "' And [Movement Type]='" & Me.cmb_Name.Column(1) & "'"
Debug.Print strFilter '
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , strFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response mdialogo, I added Nz() in the above code and this resulted in the record not being pulled at all. When I checked to see what its printing it results in [Employee Name]='' And [Movement Type]=''

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was pertaining to a datapoint that was not filled out in the table, thank you all again for your help!